# Prevent direct access to internal URLs

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, nginx, url

0

I have server1 (Javascript application running on AWS EC2 with nginx in public subnet) and server2 (api server on AWS EC2 in private subnet). In the security group of AWS for Server2 I have set port access only for Server1 security group (instead of open access).

In nginx config file I have added :

```
 location /myapi/ {
                        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:9000;  //API server2
                   }
```

Now from my application I can access server2 API via internal calls without any issue. But the issue is I can also directly access http://myapplication.com/myapi .

I want to prevent any direct access to http://myapplication.com/myapi but this should work when called from within my application running on Server1 (this IP).

I am not sure if this is OAuth domain I should be looking at to secure communication. Or is it something at AWS Security Group level or nginx level I should be setting .

Thank you for any pointers/insights.

Comment: What does it mean "direct access"? Like through internet from browser?

Comment: Yes. As in, once my application logs in http://myapplication.com then from it (application) I should be able to re-direct and invoke (internally)  http://myapplication.com/myapi . But if someone simply (in browser) executes http://myapplication.com/myapi it should fail.

Comment: Why do you make myapplication.com/myapi  public if its only for internal use? It should be private API.

Comment: Yes my question is that how do I make this (myapplication.com/myapi )  "private", while being still accessible from server 1. Sorry about the novice question. I haven't given out myapplication.com/myapi as public API, but from developer tools/network anyone could see the internal URL and access it. I want to prevent that from happening and I am not sure how to achieve it. One way would be to OAuth but I wanted to check if nginx/ AWS Security or some other way is there to achieve it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If its internal URL it can't be accessed from the internet. I think there is some misunderstanding of what you and I consider private/internal API. Private API in AWS means API only accessible within VPC. You can't access private/internal API from outside of VPC even if you know its IP address or private url.